# Create pairs but use unique element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list

```py
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
my_pairs = [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5), (6,7)]
```

And each time I iterate, I need to make pairs that are not in "my_pairs" and use each value in "my_list" one time.

So I try something but it doesn't work:

```py
for i in range(3):
    for i in range(0,7,2):
        if ((a[i],a[i+1]) not in b or (a[i+1],a[i]) not in b):
            b.append((a[i],a[i+1]))
```

I would like:

For the first iteration:

```
my_pairs = [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5), (6,7), (0,3), (2,4), (1,7), (5,6)]
```

For the second iteration:

```
my_pairs = [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5), (6,7), (0,3), (2,4), (1,7), (5,6), (1,5), (3,7), (2,6), (4,0)]
```

Comment: Can you include the expected output.

Comment: Sorry I've just included my expected output

Comment: what is the logic behind the expected out put? why (0,2) is not expectd?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
import itertools
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
my_pairs = [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5), (6,7)]
unique_pairs = [x for x in list(itertools.combinations(my_list, 2)) if x not in my_pairs]
print(unique_pairs)
```

Comment: The problem is that each iteration need to make pairs with unique value.

Answer (score 0):

does this solve your problem?

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
my_pairs = [(0,1), (2,3), (4,5), (6,7)]

from itertools import permutations
perm = permutations(my_list, 2)

for i in list(perm):
    if i not in my_pairs:
        print(i)
    else:
        print("We know " + str(i) + " already.")
```

Comment: Not really because for example 1 is used for several pairs in the same iteration and I have to use one time

Comment: Why do you need different iterations? You get all combinations with that code at once.

Comment: I want to implement that into a chess manager and all values need to be used in each round.

Comment: I do not fully understand the steps you want to go through. Could you explain this a little bit more?

Comment: Yeah sure. For example, there 8 players and 4 rounds, each round needs to make 4 pairs using each player one time but pairs need to be unique (not repeted from previous round). That's why you can't make all combinations in one time.

Comment: So, you want to have something like a tableau of a tournament. First round Player A vs B and so on.

Comment: Yeah but all players should play once in each round